# how do i get multiple records from 1 record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a product table with 15 fields like `ItemID (primary),Name ,UPC,Price,Cost, etc.`

Now I need to print labels the user can say

- from Item "ABC" I need 15 labels
- from item 'XYZ" I need 10 labels

I need a SQL statement which I will send the ItemID and the label Qty for Each record and it should give me back for each label a record for example 15 records for item "ABC" and 10 records for Item "XYZ" and so on

Comment: Why can't you simply produce the necessary number of labels in your code instead?

Comment: @Lasse - make that an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: then when get back rerun true loop it take very long we speck from a table 100,000 records

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM Mytable
Where Item = 'ABC'
GO 10
```

Will select those fields from that table 10 times in a row in 10 result sets.

Really though it sounds like you need to do what you are trying to do not in SQL, but in your calling application.

Comment: Neat, I never knew this was possible but I think this will only work in Management studio isn't it?

Comment: @lieven - correct. Either he's not using an application and he does it through SSMS, or he is using an application and it should handle the repetition.

Comment: @Nathan - then you should use your application and not SQL for this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this should be done on the client but if you insist, following duplicates each record 100 times and selects the amount you need from it.

```
;WITH ATable AS (
  SELECT Item = 'ABC'
  UNION ALL SELECT Item = 'XYZ'
)
, Temp (Item, Amount) AS (
  SELECT 'ABC', 15
  UNION ALL SELECT 'XYZ', 10
)
, q AS (
  SELECT  ID = 1
          , Item
  FROM    ATable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  ID = q.ID +1
          , q.Item
  FROM    q
  WHERE   ID < 100         
)
SELECT  q.*
FROM    q
        INNER JOIN Temp t ON t.Item = q.Item
                             AND t.Amount >= q.ID
```

Comment: @JNK, thanks but depending on the amount of rows with a possible serious performance penalty.

Comment: thanks but how can send down to the server because i don't know which item the user will select

Comment: @Nathan, you have to know at some point how many ABC's and XYZ's you need *before* you send the query to the server don't you?

Comment: i think to crate a temp table with the itemID and qty but how can then it back from there

Comment: @Nathan, if you can create that temp table, you should alos also be able to create the sql statement. Only variable is the where clause (and you don't need the WITH ATable syntax). I have edited the answer to reflect what query should get send to the server.

Comment: thanks but this maen i will need to send a where statement with over 20,000 character because the user can select over 5000 items to print

Comment: @Nathan, besides the design issue, I still don't see why you'd think that creating the temp table requires less effort than the where statement (not to mention that incorporating a temp table into this query is a complete rewrite that I'm not up to for the moment).

Comment: @lieven can you please give me some sample code how to do it with temp Table

Answer (score 0):

You create the dynamic table aliased as r below.  Works for amounts up to 2047.

```
select t.*
from 
 (select label='ABC', required=15 union all
  select label='XYZ', required=10) r
inner join tbl t
    on t.ItemID = r.label
inner join master..spt_values v
    on v.type=Number and v.number between 1 and r.required
order by t.ItemID
```